# Create and Element , clone a piece of code pressing a button Jsx react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, clone

I would be glad if someone with good heart can help me to figure out how can I solve this problem.
I just want to add a button and once we click on it a new : `<h3>G1</h3> <Multiselect options={options} displayValue="student" /></div>`
will be created , thanks in advance.
Here is my code :

```
import {Multiselect} from 'multiselect-react-dropdown';

 function addGroup(){
     var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
   var Multiselect = document.createElement("Multiselect");
   Multiselect.appendChild = <Multiselect/>;
   x.add(Multiselect);
  }
function Dropdown(){
    const data = [
      {student: '1' , id: 1},
      {student: '2' , id: 2},
      {student: '3' , id: 3}
    ]
  const [options] = useState(data);
return (
    <row>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick={addGroup()}>Add Group</button> 
       <div id="mySelect"> <h3>G1</h3>
        <Multiselect options={options} displayValue="student" /></div>
        
        
       
    </div>
    </row>
    
);
}
export default Dropdown;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use a state to keep the track of count of the dropdown.
2. Wire your state updater to the button `onClick`
3. Increase the `dropdownCount` when the user presses the button.

```
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [dropdownCount, setDropdownCount] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      {Array.from({ length: dropdownCount }).map((v, idx) => {
        return ( 
          <div>
            <p>Dropdown {idx + 1}</p>
            <MultiDropdown />
          </div>
        )
      })}
      <button onClick={() => setDropdownCount(dropdownCount + 1)}>
          Increase dropdown
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

NOTE :- Direct DOM Manipulation in React is an anti-pattern. Try to stay away from it.

Comment: Got it : "NOTE :- Direct DOM Manipulation in React is an anti-pattern. Try to stay away from it."   can you elaborate a bit on what to do?I just want to duplicate the <Multiselect/>

Comment: React uses its own representation of the DOM, called a virtual DOM, in order to figure out what to render. Usually, the virtual DOM will match the current DOM structure, and React will process changes in props and state, updating the virtual DOM and then sending the necessary changes to the real DOM. If you directly update your DOM, then  one could imagine there would be differences between virtual DOM and the real DOM causing confusion in React and causing unwanted bugs.
Regardless, did you try the above code and see it's working.

Comment: I don't know how to implement it...I am trying to figure it out...

Comment: I implemented the code that you gave me but this code is just for hiding and showing the drop-down... my issue is different...I would like to press the button and a new Multiselect will be created... so basically  this ` <div id="mySelect"> <h3>G1</h3>
        <Multiselect options={options} displayValue="student" /></div> `  ...

Comment: Everytime, someone presses the button you want new MultiSelect? @Rik Anyways, I've updated the code. You could check if this is your usecase.

Comment: Okay. Do mark it as your answer. As this will let the system know, the question is resolved.